# Do we need combine the transform-runtime and preset-env in an application?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

### Question 1

I find that there are many unnecessary duplications in the (webpack) bundle (output)result, to be specific, they all are the helpers(like `classCheck`, `objectSpread`(due to the object-spread plugin).

So, I want to reduce the duplications. If it's a library, sure, I will use transform-runtime plugin(refer to `runtime-corejs3`) to do this. But now this is an **application**, so, what's the correct way to do this?

Therefor I'm getting confused because the `transfrom-runtime` plugin is recommended **for library**(and is for the whole reduction. i.e. `core-js`, `regenerator` and the helpers). But here I **just** want to reduce the **helper** duplications, not others duplications because that **has been done** by `babel/env`.

So here the question I want to ask/discuss is that is it necessary to reduce the `helpers` duplications in an **application**, if yes, and how?

### Question 2

The other question is, `core-js/modules/es.promise.js` and  `core-js-pure/modules/es.promise.js` are exactly the same code, the main difference just is that the former has global pollution? If so, why `core-js` doesn't use(directly import) `core-js-pure` to polyfill and then add it to global? IMO, this will greatly reduce the duplications because at now the libs use `transform-runtime`(finally `core-js-pure`) but apps use `preset-env`(finally `core-js`), there is no shared/shareable codes between apps and libs, right?

Comment: it is not clear what you want to achieve in the end

Comment: @Leonardo "is it necessary to reduce the helpers duplications in an application, if yes, and how?"

Comment: Is tree shaking enabled in `webpack` ? [https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/]

Comment: @VarunGoel I thinks this is not about tree shaking because it's about duplications, not used/unused

Answer (score 3):

`@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`:  add polyfills without attatching them to the global scope.

`@babel/preset-env` with `useBuiltins: "usage"`: add polyfills to the global scope.

`@babel/preset-env` with `useBuiltIns: false (default)`: Don't add polyfills.

> So `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` is recommended for both
>   **library** and **application** to add polyfills.

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/transform-runtime',
  ],
};
```

Comment: Where do we need to mention the core-js polyfill, in @babel/preset-env or @babel/transform-runtime ?